# In GraphQL, is it guaranteed that only specified fields by the query are returned?

Tags: graphql

Does this kind of request,

```graphql
query Example {
  fruits {
    id
    fruit_name
  }
}
```

always need to return a result without any extra fields like this?

```json
{
  "data": {
    "fruits": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "fruit_name": "Manzana"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "fruit_name": "Pera"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or is it allowed to have extra fields like this?

```json
{
  "data": {
    "fruits": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "fruit_name": "Manzana",
        "some_extra_field": "red"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "fruit_name": "Pera",
        "some_extra_field": "yellow"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wonder whether GraphQL resolvers have to tree shake extra fields.

Comment: The `Query` requests will only return the fields that you query for. So `some_extra_field` will not be given back in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it guaranteed that only specified fields by the query are returned?

Yes.

> is it allowed to have extra fields?

No.  Unrequested fields will not be returned.

> I wonder whether GraphQL resolvers have to tree shake extra fields.

No.  It's not your resolvers' job.  The GraphQL implementation is responsible for filtering out un-requested fields on Object Types (see the [spec](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Executing-Fields)).